# Please anybody check my code to see what's wrong with it

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getAvg(int a, int b, int c);
int main()
{
  int a,b,c;
  int i;
  int avg[5];

  char name[5][10] ;
  int korean[5], english[5], maths[5] ;
  char message[2][10] = {"Pass","No Pass"};

  for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  {
      printf("Enter your marks <name,korean,english,maths \n");
      scanf("%s%d%d%d",name[i],&korean[i],&english[i],&maths[i]);
  }


  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {


    printf("name:%s, korean:%d, english:%d, maths:%d, average:%d",name[i],korean[i],english[i],maths[i],avg[i]);
    avg[i] = getAvg(a,b,c);

    if (avg[i]>60)
    {
      printf("==%s",message[0]);
    }

    else
    {
      printf("==%s",message[1]);
    }

 }


int getAvg(int a, int b, int c)
  {
    int avg;

    avg = (a+b+c)/3;

    return avg;
  }
 }
```

I want to print like this

```
Enter your marks <name,korean,english,maths>
kim 10 50 60
Enter your marks <name,korean,english,maths>
hanna 50 60 70
Enter your marks <name,korean,english,maths>
lee 80 70 60
Enter your marks <name,korean,english,maths>
lori 70 80 90
Enter your marks <name,korean,english,maths>
kang 60 70 80

name:kim,korean:10,english:50,maths:60,average:40 == no pass
name:hanna,korean:50,english:60,maths:70,average:60 == no pass
name:lee,korean:80,english:70,maths:60,average:70 == pass
name:lori,korean:70,english:80,maths:90,average:80 == pass
name:kang,korean:60,english:70,maths:80,average:70 == pass
```

I'm really sorry if it turns out to be my mistakes or the question is too elementary.. it's due in 5 hours and i couldn't figure out what's wrong.. it keeps telling me that the getAve function is undefined reference and i see nothing wrong with it.. please anybody kindly help me? :(

Comment: You have placed the definition of `getAvg` *inside*  the definition of `main`.  Put it at the global scope and your code will compile.  Do pay attention to the other compiler warnings, though.

Comment: Also, in the main body, you may want to change avg[i] = getAvg(a,b,c); to use the actual values which are input.  a,b,c is not set when you make that call.  It should be getAvg(korean[i],english[i],maths[i]). In addition, you may want to call the function before you print out the values.

Comment: @Will Might be a more appropriate wording.  However, I did (after moving the definition) run it through GCC and it did compile fine, with warnings only shown with `-Wall`.

Comment: @5gon12eder Not compiling with `-wall` is crazy though, especially in the case of a beginner like the OP. After all, `-Wuninitialized` (and `-Wmaybe-uninitialized`) are a pretty strong indicator to where else he or she screwed up.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAvg` is inside `main`. Move it out (or, equivalently, move one outer brace from end of your code to just above `getAvg` definition start). There is also something wrong with the calculation of averages, but that's a logical error, not a syntactic one. (Specifically, you're calculating the average of `a`, `b` and `c` - check where you define the value of those variables, and you're printing stuff before you calculate it).

Answer (score 1):

You get "undefined reference to getAvg function" because you did not close `main` before defining the `getAvg` function. Just move the last `}` before the function definition and that error should be gone !

Then,You call the function like this

```
avg[i] = getAvg(a,b,c);
```

But `a`,`b` and `c` are uninitialized ! So you need

```
a=korean[i];
b=english[i];
c=maths[i];
```

Before it. You also print `avg[i]` before you calculate it. So, move the `printf` after the function call to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your brace positioning, also there is a problem here:

```
printf("name:%s, korean:%d, english:%d, maths:%d, average:%d",name[i],korean[i],english[i],maths[i],avg[i]);
avg[i] = getAvg(a,b,c);
```

You have to calculate the average before you display it. Also, `a, b, c` are uninitialized variables. You probably meant:

```
avg[i] = getAvg( korean[i], english[i], maths[i] );
printf("name:%s, korean:%d, english:%d, maths:%d, average:%d",
        name[i], korean[i], english[i], maths[i], avg[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

first you put `getAvg(...)` outside of `main()`

now call `getAvg(...)` before printing `avg[i];`

```
avg[i] = getAvg(korean[i],english[i],maths[i]);
printf("name:%s, korean:%d, english:%d, maths:%d, average:%d",name[i],korean[i],english[i],maths[i],avg[i]);
```